# Setting up Phppgadmin 5.0.2 with Xampp 1.7.4

Tags: php, postgresql, xampp, phppgadmin

I was asked to perform(first time) a task in PHP with PostgreSQL for the purpose I intalled XAMPP 1.7.4, PostgreSQL 9.X, I was unaware how to setup phpPgadmin(5.0.2) so I googled and found [Configuration Instruction here](http://notepad.patheticcockroach.com/628/adding-postgresql-portable-to-xampp-on-windows/); [and here](http://practicalfoss.blogspot.com/2008/09/how-to-install-postgresql-and.html)

after configuring all this i found following error when i tried to https://localhost/phppgadmin

> Your PHP installation does not support
>   PostgreSQL. You need to recompile PHP
>   using the --with-pgsql configure
>   option.

I googled again found some possible reasons those are

1. you did't restarted aphace
2. the php.ini you changed is not the right php.ini file, make it sure from xampp console under phpinfo()

I have checked both but still error is there no change at all. please someone help me, I already spent more than a business day, THANKs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried following article and it worked.

http://programmingmeetsmath.wordpress.com/2010/12/21/a-step-by-step-guide-of-installing-apache-php5-postgresql-windows/

Answer (score 9):

As I replied there, copying around php/libpq.dll into apache/bin should (hopefully) do the trick.

Comment: I tried this, but I am experience different error than this, So change yet :(

Comment: Does phpinfo() show postgresql support as enabled? If yes, I think it'd be worth trying postgre version 8.3.x: http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgdownload#windows

Comment: There is no info about postgresql apearing in phpinfo() (i am looking in xampp page under phpinfo())

Comment: anyway I am going to try this artical now :(
http://programmingmeetsmath.wordpress.com/2010/12/21/a-step-by-step-guide-of-installing-apache-php5-postgresql-windows/

Comment: So, basically, was it just postre PDO missing or did you do a full install from scratch?

Answer (score 2):

Did you uncomment the line:

```
extension=php_pgsql.dll
```

in

```
C:\xampp\php\php.ini
```

and after that restart Apache?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you installed the postgresql module?

Just do a `phpinfo();` to find out which modules are installed.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. Everything uncommented and displayed in phpinfo()

Finally I went to xampp:/php/ directory and double clicked php.exe to execute

And the command prompt showed the error in my php.ini

I fixed the missing semicolon in a line and everything went smooth. Hope it helps someone